# How to count and measure multiple key presses

Tags: c++, count, key, measure

I am trying to develop a tool for gaming for key analysis to be able to make the right keybindings without having to spend 1000+ hours in game.

The idea:
The program is supposed to count and measure key duration during gameplay and at the end output the stats to see which keys were the most useful according to their quantity and duration pressed in game. Afterwards the most useful keys can be rebinded as close as possible to reach and the less useful keys can be rebinded further away from fingers.

I have already wrote some code to accomplish this task for key "A" and "W", but as I add more keys the code is becoming repetitive and gigantic.

The question:
How can I use std::vector or std::array to simplify my code and do it for all keys at once to avoid repetitions? (Forgive me for my dumbness I have read multiple articles on std::vector and std::array, but still cannot properly implement them in my code.)

This is my code and as I add more keys it becomes larger and larger:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <windows.h>


int main()
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start, finish;
    std::chrono::duration<float> duration;

    int aKeyCount{0};
    int wKeyCount{0};
    float akeyTotalDuration{0.0};
    float wkeyTotalDuration{0.0};
    bool aKeyReleased{false};
    bool wKeyReleased{false};

    while (true)
    {
//"A"-Key
        if (GetAsyncKeyState('A') & 0x8000)
        {
            if (!aKeyReleased)
            {
                ++aKeyCount;
                std::cout << "A_Times_Pressed: " << aKeyCount << std::endl;
                start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

            }
            aKeyReleased = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(aKeyReleased)
            {
                finish = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
                duration = finish - start;
                akeyTotalDuration += duration.count() * 1000.0f;
                std::cout << "A_Hold_Duration [ms]: " << duration.count() * 1000.0f << "ms" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "A_Total_Hold_Duration [ms]: " << akeyTotalDuration << "ms" << std::endl;
            }
            aKeyReleased = false;
        }
//"W"-Key
        if (GetAsyncKeyState('W') & 0x8000)
        {
            if (!wKeyReleased)
            {
                ++wKeyCount;
                std::cout << "W_Times_Pressed: " << wKeyCount << std::endl;
                start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

            }
            wKeyReleased = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(wKeyReleased)
            {
                finish = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
                duration = finish - start;
                wkeyTotalDuration += duration.count() * 1000.0f;
                std::cout << "W_Hold_Duration [ms]: " << duration.count() * 1000.0f << "ms" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "W_Total_Hold_Duration [ms]: " << wkeyTotalDuration << "ms" << std::endl;
            }
            wKeyReleased = false;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code for 'A' key and 'W' key is almost same, so you can have a array which contains all key you need processing, than use a for loop to do it. Like this:

```cpp
const int keysNeedProcessCount = 2; // for example, you have 2 keys need processing, 'A' key and 'W' key
char keysNeedProcess[keysNeedProcessCount] = {'A', 'B'};
int keysCount[keysNeedProcessCount] = {0};
float keysTotalDuration[keysNeedProcessCount] = {0.0};
bool keysReleased[keysNeedProcessCount] = {false};

for (int i = 0; i < keysNeedProcessCount; i++) {
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(keysNeedProcess[i]) & 0x8000)
    {
        if (!keysReleased[i])
        {
            ++keysCount[i];
            std::cout << keysNeedProcess[i] << "_Times_Pressed: " << keysCount[i] << std::endl;
            start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        }
        keysReleased[i] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(keysReleased[i])
        {
            finish = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            duration = finish - start;
            keysTotalDuration[i] += duration.count() * 1000.0f;
            std::cout << keysNeedProcess[i] << "_Hold_Duration [ms]: " << duration.count() * 1000.0f << "ms" << std::endl;
            std::cout << keysNeedProcess[i] << "_Total_Hold_Duration [ms]: " << keysTotalDuration[i] << "ms" << std::endl;
        }
        keysReleased[i] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a nice idea and I think it was what I was looking for. I am trying it right now. Thank you